# Qt debug won't stop on breakpoint

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

I just installed qt creator sdk and the windows debug thing. When I try to debug the debugger comes with the warning:

Preferred debugger engine for debugging binaries of type 'x86-windows-msys-pe-23bit' is not available. 
The debugger engine Cdb engine will be used as a fallback
Details: There is no gdb binary available for binaries in format 'x86-windows-msys-pe-32bit'
Then the program start building.

When I set breakpoints into the program the debugger won't stop at de breakpoints. I've tried a lot of things to let the debugger work properly but nothing has helped so far. If anybody has a suggestion please let me know. I think it maybe has something to do with the compiler I'm using which is something like mingw but i have no idea how to set another compiler or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know msys, most likely you do not need the msys compiler, try mingw compiler itself from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files).
make sure to install gcc, and gdb.

Since you did not mention I assume it is Windows, as a side note, if gdb gave you headache on Windows please use the mingw version bundled with [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads) it is probably older though (look for the one that comes with mingw bundled).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get either gdb/cdb installed with Qt to be able to debug your code. Try editing the options in Tools->Options in Qt Creator and pointing to correct gdb paths. That should solve this problem. There are other options available there to configure the gdb options in the settings dialog.